# Authentication not working properly after using fingerprint authentication in Ububtu 14.04

Tags: password, authentication, fingerprint-reader

I installed fingerprint-gui to use fingerprint scanner in my thinkpad. 
The commands used were

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:fingerprint/fingerprint-gui && sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install libbsapi policykit-1-fingerprint-gui fingerprint-gui

Everything is working completely fine, from login screen to sudo access in terminal, but the only problem is when I try to update my system through gui in systems setting, I am prompted to enter password, after I enter the password, I am asked to 1)Authenticate or 2)Cancel
NO matter how many times I click the authenticate button, nothing happens.

Also recently when I booted my pc, a message popped that the system occurred a error/failure (probably because of the authentication issue stated above). But again when I choose to send the report to Ubuntu I am prompted to enter the password and the same thing happens as stated above. So I am not even able to send error report.

Please help, Thanks